# Как сделать модальное окно?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Всем добрый день.В файле index.php  есть ссылка которая ведёт на другой файл (db.php) через который добавляется  новая запись в бд.(`<td colspan="3"><a  href="db.php">Добавить клиента</a>  </td>`  ) Как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в  файле index.php в модальном окне открывалась форма db.php ? Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот файл index.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Рекламное агенство</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      <? include "css/style.css" ?>

      </style>

</head>
<body> 

    <?php 
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","reklama","reklama") ;
$db=mysql_select_db(reklama);
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysql_error());
}
$rezult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti");
mysql_close();
?>

<table align="center" >
<!--    <tr>Информация о клиентах</tr> -->
<tr  id="Add"  > 
   <td colspan="3"><a  href="db.php">Добавить клиента</a>  </td>
   <td colspan="3"><a  href="delete.php">Удалить клиента</a>  </td>
   <td colspan="3"><a  href="edit.php">Редактировать клиента</a>  </td>

</tr > 
<tr > 
<td id= "header"colspan="9"><b><font size="4" face="Arial" >Информация о клиентах </font></b></td>  <!--  тут растягиваем на 8 столбиков -->
</tr >

<tr >
     <th>Номер заказа </th>
     <th>Клиент </th>
     <th >ОП форма </th >
      <th >Наименование </th >
     <th>Отрасль </th >
     <th >Телефон </th >
      <th >Email </th >
     <th>Контактное лицо </th>
     <th >Должность </th >
     <th > Дата выполнения</th >
     <th >Дата добавления </th >
     <th >Время </th >
      <th >Действия </th >
      <!-- <th >Действия </th > -->
 </tr>
 <?php 
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezult)) 
{ ?> 
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['klient']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['op_forma']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['naimen']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['otrasl']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['kont_lico']?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['dolznost']?></td>
 <td><?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$row['date1'])->format('d-‌​m-Y');?></td>
 <td><?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$row['date'])->format('d-‌​m-Y');?></td>

 <td><?php echo $row['time']?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?> 
</table>
 <!--      </section> -->

     <!-- Footer -->
    <!--  <footer>
     <div class="wrapper"> 

     </div>
     </footer> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Вот файл db.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/tcal.js"></script> <!-- //календарь -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar/tcal.css" /> <!-- //календарь -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Добавление клиента</title>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include the script -->
<script src="alertifyjs/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!-- include the style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/alertify.min.css" />
<!-- include a theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/themes/default.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
$ ("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // !!!
    var dannie = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dannie,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {

                  alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                  alertify.success('Клиент успешно добавлен!'); 

 // alertify.success('Current position : ' + alertify.get('notifier','position'));
                      } 
            else {          
            alertify.alert("Ошибка");
                 }
                }
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
клиент<br/>
<input type="text" name="klient" /><br/>
ОП_форма <br/>
<textarea name="op_forma" ></textarea> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->
Наимен <br/>
<input type="text" name="naimen"  /><br/><br/>
отрасль <br/>
<input type="text" name="otrasl"  /><br/><br/>
telefon <br/>
<input type="text" name="telefon"  /><br/><br/>
email <br/>
<input type="text" name="email"  /><br/><br/>
Контактное лицо <br/>
<input type="text" name="kont_lico"  /><br/><br/>
Должность <br/>
<input type="text" name="dolznost"  /><br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date ('Y-m-d');?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date ('H:i:s');?>" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="date1" class="tcal"  value="" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit"  id="send"  value="Добавить" />
<input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Очистить форму" onclick="this.form.reset();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form сделать красиво, но нужно немного переписать код  и смерджить оба файла. 
если мерджить не хочется - можно простым include-ом сделать в DIV.
Или на js написать подгрузку странички в DIV при нажатии на ссылку.

В общем на Ваш вкус :)

Comment: **_можно простым include-ом сделать в DIV_**  А как это сделать? есть инструкция какая?

Comment: @roman , пример: <div id="right">
   <script>
      document.write('<?php echo include_once "include.php";?>');
   </script>
</div>

Comment: @roman  [вот есть еще](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443759/javascript-innerhtml-include-php)

Answer (score 1):

1) Самое простое - указать target

```
<a  href="db.php" target="_blank">Добавить клиента</a>
```

2) Чуть сложнее и менее надёжно - windows.open

```
<a id="addclient" href="db.php">Добавить клиента</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addclient").click(function(){
      var newWin = window.open("db.php", "newWinName", "");
       newWin.focus();
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

3) Наиболее сложный способ - переписать db.php  и загружать в div, "эмулирующий" окно.